# Display a value when modifying a control using dat.GUI

Tags: dat.gui

Can anybody help me what I am showing in the image?

*[1]: http://www.romualdorivera.com/three.js/dat.GUI_img_01.jpg*

Here is my code:

```
var gui = new dat.GUI();
parameters = {  x: 1,   area: 1,}

gui.add(parameters, 'x', 1,400).name("Scale XY (in)").onChange();

gui.add(parameters, "area", value).name("Surface area=").onChange( x = x * 2);
```

Comment: `x * 2` is the calculation of a perimeter, not an area.

Comment: Yes, I meant any formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a plane on the XZ-plane (1 x 1):

```
var planeGeom = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(1, 1);
planeGeom.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeom, new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  color: "green"
}));
scene.add(plane);
```

then you can create an instance of `dat.GUI` and set its controllers like this:

```
parameters = {
  x: 1,
  area: 1,
}
var gui = new dat.GUI();
gui.add(parameters, 'x', 1, 400).name("Scale XY (in)").onChange(
  function(value) {
    plane.scale.set(value, 1, value);
    parameters.area = value * value; // update the value of parameters.area
  }
);
gui.add(parameters, "area", 1).name("Surface area=").listen(); // listen for updating of the value
```

It's based on the [example](https://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#9--Updating-the-Display-Automatically) of dat.GUI

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/514d4kmy/) example.